# Integral equation $\int_0^{\infty} \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt=g(\omega)=\frac {1}{\omega^2+2},\omega>0, 0$ otherwise. Find $\phi(t)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

Find $\int_0^{\infty} \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt=g(\omega)=\frac {1}{\omega^2+2},\omega>0, 0$ otherwise. Find $\phi(t)$.

Here is what I tried but I came to a strange result and don't know if it's correct.

I prolonged the $\phi(t)$ function to make it odd so I could prolong the integral over the all real axis and we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\sin(\omega t)dt = 2g(w)$$

We multiply by $-i$ on both sides and we get:
$$-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\sin(\omega t)dt = -2ig(w)$$

Since $\phi(t)$ is odd we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\cos(\omega t)dt = 0$$

If we add them togheter we get:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt = -2ig(w)$$

We use the inversion formulae now:

$$f(\omega)=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(t)e^{i\omega t}dt$$

Where $F(t)$ would be the fourier transform of $f$.

Thus, we get:

$$\phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {-2i}{\omega^2+2}e^{-i\omega t}d\omega$$

Using residuum theorem we only have to evaluate the functions residues in $i\sqrt{2}$.

And we get:

$$\phi(t) = -\frac{e^{-\sqrt{2}t}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

And I feel like it's not completely correct.

Comment: I don't blame you for your misgivings:$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty\sin(\omega t)\exp(-\sqrt{2}t)dt=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Im\int_0^\infty\exp(-(\sqrt{2}-i\omega)t)dt=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Im\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-i\omega}\\=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Im\frac{\sqrt{2}+i\omega}{2+\omega^2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\omega}{2+\omega^2}.$$

Comment: What's that symbol after the first equal sign?

Comment: If you mean $\Im$ (which you can write with `Im`), it's "imaginary part of".

Comment: So to speak, here you checked if the Fourier transform backwards gives what it should, right? Then why did you start this with sin and from 0 to infinity and not with $e^{-i\omega t}$ and from -infinity to infinity?

Comment: I was checking whether it worked in your original problem, which uses $\int_0^\infty\sin(\omega t)dt$ instead of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-i\omega t)dt$.

Comment: @J.G. Then What I did wrong?

Comment: I suspect the solution has $\lim_{t\to0^+}\phi(t)\ne0$, so you can't extend it to an odd function without it becoming discontinuous.

Comment: @J.G. Then how should I proceed?

Comment: That depends. Where did the problem come from? Given the discontinuity sought at $\omega=0$, are you sure a solution exists?

Comment: @J.G. It's from an exam, It probably should have, I'm not sure

Comment: For $\omega > 0$, $H(\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt$ then $H(-\omega) = -H(\omega)$ so as the OP stated it there is no solution

Comment: @reuns can you please re-explain? Why exactly there isnt any solution?

Comment: Because $\frac1{\omega^2+2}$ is even while $H(\omega)$ is odd.

Comment: but if phi is odd and sin is odd then H must be even

Comment: With $H$ defined as I and you did it is odd

Comment: @reuns I don't get it, I defined phi as odd, sin is also odd, then that H must be even and then has a solution, if I would define phi as even then H is odd thus it doens't have any solutions, What am I missing?

Comment: The function you defined is $\int_0^\infty$ not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$

Comment: Continue........

Comment: Both $F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt$ and $H(\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt$ are odd.That's completely obvious so how can you be stuck at this ?

Comment: Why?? Because is $\phi$ is odd and $\sin$ is odd then $\phi \times \sin$ is even... and odd means $\phi(-t) = -\phi(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely dumb answer that solves your question. As the comments noted, there appeared to be an odd mismatch between the equation and the placement of $\omega$, namely odd/even-ness. Put another way,

$$\lim_{\omega\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\omega^2+2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

but the integral seems to vanish there. The way I found to fix it was to suggest that perhaps $\phi$ has a pole of order $1$ at $\omega = 0$

$$\int_0^\infty \phi(t) \sin(\omega t)dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(t)}{ \omega } \sin(\omega t) dt$$

Next, I recognized that form of $g(\omega)$ from the result of integration by parts of trig functions times exponentials, namely

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-at}\sin(\omega t) dt = \frac{\omega}{\omega^2+a^2}$$

Picking $a=\sqrt{2}$ leads us to our final answer:

$$\phi(t) = e^{-\sqrt{2}t}\frac{H(\omega)}{\omega} \implies \int_0^\infty \phi(t) \sin(t) dt = g(\omega)$$

where the factor of $H(\omega)$, the Heaviside step function, ensures that the integral vanishes for $\omega < 0$. It seems you almost had it, but made the assumption that $\phi(t)$ must be independent of $\omega$. Unfortunately, that assumption would lead you to the contradiction above.

There is no unique answer, either, as

$$\phi(t) = \frac{2}{\pi t}\frac{H(\omega)}{\omega^2+2}$$

would have also worked and was the first answer I arrived at.